# Top Activity is removed whenever started from play store and put back to background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-manifest

My App has different activities. The first Activity shown is the `SplashActivity`, which will instantly either open the `AuthActivity` or if authorized the `MainActivty`.

From the `MainActivity` it is possible to navigate to further activities, i'll now just reference as `OtherActivity`.

My Problem is:
Whenever i start the app from the Play Store Installation dialog that says "open app", then log in, navigate to `OtherActivity`, put the app in background and click on the launcher icon of my app, the `MainActivity` is shown.

However, after killing the app and opening it via the launcher icon, navigating to `OtherActivity`, putting the app in background, opening it again via the launcher, the `OtherActivity` is shown.

**The Question:** How can this be fixed, so that the `OtherActivity` always stays on top?

So far i could find out, that the difference between launching from playstore and launching from  launcher is the category: `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

simulate **Play Store**: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example/com.example.SplashActivity`

simulate **Launcher**: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -n com.example/com.example.SplashActivity`

The manifest looks like this:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:scheme="com.example" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:scheme="com.example" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**Edit:** I think this is related to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64108432)

**Edit:** The `OtherActivity` is registered in the manifest and started as follows:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".OtherActivity"
    android:label=""
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

```kotlin
startActivity(
    Intent().apply {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        setClassName(context, "com.example.OtherActivity")
    }
)
```

Comment: could you please add some other activity's tag as well? in your manifest code so I can see what you have for them. One or two that stays up when you are putting app into background

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati the added code shows the `OtherActivity` which should stay open, but doesn't, when started via play store, put to background and opened via launcher.

Comment: Thanks, so from google store when you open, it shows first `Splashactivity` then moves to `MainActivity` right? or it just resumes `MainActivity`?

Comment: 1. From PlayStore, it first shows `SplashActivity` then `MainActivity`. 
2. Navigate to `OtherActivity`
3. Put App in Background
4. Open via Launcher
5. `MainActivity` is shown

Comment: could you please add your activity intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass these flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` your activity will be root activity.

I think what happens is that two intents are mixed up

1. from Google store
2. Launch icon are opening your app,

So you could add in your `MainActivity` and/or `SplashActivity` oncreate() method to prevent this behavior,

```
 if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So far, it seems that it is working! Thank you very much. Could you explain a little further what is happening?

Comment: @JuliusHetzel Intent from google store and lancherIcon are different, they both create new task in your application, so there are two Tasks created with different stack of activities 1. Intent stack of Google store - Splash, Main, other 2. Stack 2 of launcher, main and otherAc... so the previous task already exists, if not roottask, you are simply destroying launcher acitivity stack and return to your google intent task. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack you can get more info from here.